# How much does it cost to write/read to FirebaseRealtimeDatabase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have currently opted for the Firebase "Spark" package and I can't find the cost of queries for Firebase Realtime Database.
Here is what it says for FRD:
Simultaneous connections help
GB stored
GB downloaded
Multiple databases per project

Maybe that's what it says in Cloud Storage :
GB stored
GB downloaded
Upload operations
Download operations
Multiple buckets per project

But I'd like to make sure. If so, "Upload operations" corresponds to setValue and Download operations to "observe", right?

Also, I would like to know how the Spark formula works if we wait for the limits imposed. Will the next operations be blocked or will we automatically switch to the Blaze formula?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

The **Spark Plan** of Firebase is very generous compared to other BaaS’ in our current industry, Firebase already offers scalability, and elasticity. Under the spark plan while it’s for development and testing apps, I assure you it can run an app with over 400-600 active users everyday (Assuming that you have a valid FS Rule Set and already take advantage of NoSQL and Real-Time Database)

To properly address your concerns, I’d suggest that you immediately upgrade to a Blaze-Plan, Under the blaze plan, you’re not charged unless your usage exceed the amount of resources beyond Spark-Plan. Hence the term scalability, you only will pay for the resources that went beyond Spark Plan.

If you suspect that your app is vulnerable to a large userbase upon launch, I suggest that you set up a valid Firestore/realtime database rules and immediately drop unneeded requests.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, I might as well go straight to the Blaze plan, Thanks !

Comment: You’re welcome, let me know if you had any other questions

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how the Spark formula works if we wait for the limits imposed. Will the next operations be blocked or will we automatically switch to the Blaze formula?

From the Firebase [pricing FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#pricing):

> What happens if I exceed Spark plan storage or download limits for Realtime Database?
>
> To provide you with a predictable price, the resources available to you in the Spark plans are capped. This means that when you exceed any plan limit in any month, your app will be turned off to prevent any further resource usage and additional charges.

So the operations will be blocked until either the next month, or until you upgrade to the paid/Blaze plan.